# How to find the absolute path of the source of a mounted device?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

How can I find the absolute or full path of a mount from /proc/self/mountinfo file?

Comment: Does `awk '{print $5}' /proc/self/mountinfo` work for you for all mounts? For a specific mount maybe `awk '/\/home/{print $5}' /proc/self/mountinfo`.

Comment: We have root of the mount on 5th position. I want to know the full path of source

Comment: That information is not in mountinfo. Are you looking for `awk '/\/home/{print $1} /etc/mtab`?

Comment: Actually I only have access to /proc/self/mountinfo file as I am accessing it in my Go application as part of mount-utils package.

Comment: In that case look in `/proc/self/mounts`.

Comment: mounts file doesn't seem to have a source column.

Comment: The first field is the source, second is the destination. One posting documenting the pseudo-file is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122123/how-to-interpret-proc-mounts). For one of my systems, `grep ' / ' /proc/mounts` returns a line beginning with `/dev/mapper/vg0-root`. What are you seeing in field 1?

Comment: I am seeing the device name for the first field.

Comment: I'm now confused. What is the difference between the device name and the source?